# Unity Terrain Texture Stretching

Tags: unity-game-engine, terrain, unity3d-terrain

I am new to Unity's terrain system and was trying to create a terrain for a game. I finished my terrain and then wanted to begin texturing it, to my dismay the textures that I'd try would become extremely stretched due to the height I have some parts of the terrain set at. I have been looking for a solution to this problem and I tried to do the Triplanar Shader mapping but it seems to not work either or I did it wrong. All of the floors look fine its just the sides of the terrain that get stretched. What should I do to try to fix this issue? Am beginner

Comment: For a beginner it is very hard to fix, I have had the same issues myself. My advice would be to look at tutorials on the matter and see if it helps, however they tend to be sort of complex since it is not an easy problem to solve.

Comment: Ah, I see thanks for the comment. I'll keep trying!